# this keyword used as a method argument

Tags: java, this

I know there are a lot of questions about the `this` keyword in Java and I seriously read several and I watched some tutorials on it. But it still confuses me because I have to add a property listener to my JFormattedField and then they add a `this` keyword in the parameter.

Now I know you can do something like `this.a = a` and `this.a` refers to the global variable this, and also when you use `this("hello", 13)` that refers to the constructors with those specific parameters. But what happens when someone does this?

```
someField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);
```

What does that refer to?  This is in context [to this Oracle tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: `this` is **not** a "global variable".

Comment: `this` means current object

Comment: In [your example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html#addPropertyChangeListener%28java.lang.String,%20java.beans.PropertyChangeListener%29), `this` refers to your `JFormattedTextField` instance which (apparently) implements `PropertyChangeListener`.

Comment: I've edited out the "I don't understand" portions because they don't add much value to the discussion.  They don't even add clarifying context or a reference for us to bounce off of.

Comment: So this refers to an object of jformattedfield? In my example of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simplest terms `this` generally refers to current instance. When you pass it in method like:

```
someField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);
```

you are actually passing current instance of the class to the method. Using this current instance lots of modifications can be done. So you should not pass it until and unless you are sure what you are doing.

Comment: So basically I am passing an object of the class I am in as a parameter?

Comment: Thank you.. this was made in simplest terms that I guess a dummy could understand. Sorry for the troubles and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The method call is made from within another object. `this`, in this context, refers to that object, i. e. the caller's context.

Comment: So this is referring to an object but which one? Sorry this is really confusing me and I know again there are a lot of threads about this.

Comment: @JohnnyInno1 "The current one". The one whose method you write it in. In the Oracle tutorial's case, an instance of `FormattedTextFieldDemo`.

Comment: The line `rateField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);` means: notify _"me"_ (the `FormattedTextFieldDemo` object) if the value in rateField changes. The `FormattedTextFieldDemo` object will then receive a PropertyChangeEvent.

Comment: Thank you immibis! That was something I could understand.